# Return Parents With Only One Child

Tags: t-sql

In a Parent and Child relationship, I'm trying to return Parents that only have one Child and a where clause applied to the only child `firstname like 'tom'`

t-sql pseudo: `parents with only one child and that child's name is tom`

```
select p.* 

from parents p 
  inner join children c on c.parentId = p.id

where count(c.id) = 1 -- ??? with only 1 child ???
  and c.firstname like 'tom'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If they have 2 children, one named Tom and the other Mary, should they be returned or not?

Comment: no, if a parent has 2 children, ignored completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the primary key of `children` is (horror) `id`:

```
select p.* 

from parents p 
  inner join children c on c.parentId = p.id

where c.firstname like 'tom'
  and not exists
      ( select 1 from children c2
        where c2.parentId = p.id
          and c2.id <> c.id
      ) ;
```

or using `GROUP BY`:

```
select p.* 

from parents p 
  inner join 
    ( select parentid
      from children c 
      group by parentid
      having min(id) = max(id)          -- you could use instead:  count(*)=1  here
         and min(firstname) like 'tom'
    ) c
    on c.parentid = p.id ;
```